# Error while filtering english language tweets only

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, data-extraction

I am extracting tweets written only in English Language and I used the following filter

```
stream.filter(stall_warnings=True, track=['#brain'], languages=['en'])
```

But unfortunately this filter returns a tweet which is combination of English and some other language

Please see the tweet [here](https://twitter.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FCMclhAnyA4&src=typd)

How can I extract a tweet which is written only in English Language?

Note: I am sorry if it is wrong for linking some other's tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweets are classified by Twitter on one language or another. Their classification isn't always correct. If the tweet uses multiple languages they just assign it to one of them.

So you will need to filter them in your app against a dictionary or using some language detection libraries to be 100% sure that only English Language is used on the tweets you receive.

Source: https://blog.twitter.com/2013/introducing-new-metadata-for-tweets